# Receiving notification/event/signal of usb device insertion in c++

Tags: c++, c, linux, usb

I have been looking for a while, but I have not been able to find an answer to this question. I am trying to receive a connection notification for a specific usb device. Here is what I have/know:

I am running the linux kernel version 3.2. I have the id's needed to identify the usb device. I have created a kernel module for reading and writing to the device. The kernel module has been tested and works properly. The kernel module creates /dev/Component#.

I am trying to write a program that is notified of a USB device connection event and thus will not need to loop over the /dev/Component# and check if the file exists. My hope is that there is a signal/notification/event that already exists. I have seen the libusb, but my understanding is that you are really just creating a loop that reads all the devices. I have considered adding a syscall, but recompiling the kernel isn't really an option.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

SgtSquatlow

Comment: Is a hotplug script sufficient?  If not, take a look at the hotplug source.

Comment: I'd recommend you to add `udev` rule that will notify your deamon program upon insertion.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code needs to be portable and not all systems that I will run the code on have/use udev.

Comment: https://github.com/Jinjinov/Usb.Events/blob/master/Usb.Events/UsbEventWatcher.Linux.c

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution using dbus. First you should install the library libdbus-glib (on Debian / Ubuntu the package is called `libdbus-glib-1-dev`) if it is not installed yet. Then you can peak a program [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011603/dbus-glib-bindings-udisks-error), compile the program like this:

```
gcc -o dbus-usb dbus-usb.c $(pkg-config --libs --cflags dbus-glib-1)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18632874)

Comment: @Simon Shine i have linked a stackoverflow example. i cannot see how a stackoverflow link become invalid.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice at first. You're quite right. This answer was automatically flagged for being short. I've improved on the formatting (using `$(...)` instead of backticks) and upvoted it.